# KeyError: kafka.producer.record_accumulator.RecordBatch

Tags: python, asynchronous, apache-kafka, send, keyerror

Using kafka-python api to send a bunch of messages to a topic. A portion of messages get successfully sent to the topic but not all of them are sent before the program terminates with the following error message:

```
KeyError: <kafka.producer.record_accumulator.RecordBatch object at 0x143d290>
Batch is already closed -- ignoring batch.done()
Error processing errback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/future.py", line 79, in _call_backs
    f(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/producer/sender.py", line 185, in _failed_produce
    self._complete_batch(batch, error, -1, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/producer/sender.py", line 243, in _complete_batch
    self._accumulator.deallocate(batch)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/producer/record_accumulator.py", line 507, in deallocate
    self._incomplete.remove(batch)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/producer/record_accumulator.py", line 587, in remove
    return self._incomplete.remove(batch)
```

Every run a different number of messages are actually received in my topic. The problem appears to be that kafka producer.send calls do not complete sending before the program reaches its end.

According to kafka documentations producer.send is an async method which is probably the root cause - not all async threads complete sending before the process is killed:

> The send() method is asynchronous. When called it adds the record to a
>   buffer of pending record sends and immediately returns. This allows
>   the producer to batch together individual records for efficiency.

There are a number of naive solutions for this (such as setting the `batch.size` to a low number) that could cause a performance bottleneck.

How would you address this issue **without compromising the performance too much**?

Answer (score 4):

Just call `producer.flush()` before exit.

Comment: that was the first thing I tried. As noted in the description, the producer appears to have dispatched async calls to send the messages already but they haven't completed yet probably because the batch size is not small enough.

Comment: @r2d2oid you problem is quite straightforward. You explained it yourself - the program exit before producer send all messages. Trying to solve it by playing with batch size is just incorrect. If you have something in buffer you must wait until sending will be finished. [flush](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaProducer.html) will block you programm until everythin will be send, that's it. If you encounter this bug after you call `producer.flush()` after you have sent your last record then I am wrong and just don't understand your problem (bug in kafka-python?).